# How to make clusters far from the center in the same layout more compact (igraph or ggraph package in R)?

Tags: r

When making the network diagram, I wanted to highlight the core edge structure (nodes with large degree in the center). However, the clusters are not connected, resulting in some small clusters being too far from the center and thus not being able to visualize the central structure. What should I do to solve this problem?

library(igraph)

deg <- degree(net_pc, mode="all")

l <- layout_with_gem(net_pc)

plot(net_pc, layout=l, vertex.size = log(deg), vertex.label.cex = 0.7, vertex.label.dist = 0.7,edge.color = "lightblue",edge.curved = 0.2)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV76p.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.